Under what cirumstances does a negative double call for a NT response?
At matchpoints with neither vulnerable, and a new partner, I opened one club in second position with ♠QJ75 ♥AJ4 ♦4 ♣AJ964. Left hand opponent overcalled one spade. Partner doubled (negative) with ♠3 ♥K872 ♦Q53 ♣KQ753.
I interpret a negative double as "I don't like your suit, and I don't fancy defending against the opponent's overcall, so please choose between the remaining two (red) suits." I bid two hearts to show my three cards in that suit.
The best contract was 4 clubs, but I didn't know about partner's club holding, although she knew "something" about mine. Given her bidding, I would have expected her to hold something more like ♠3 ♥K872 ♦KQ753 ♣Q53.
She said that she thought of her club holding as the backbone of a no trumper, and wanted me to bid one NT instead of two hearts. (We got a bottom for going down at a seven card heart fit, while others made 2NT, (but not 3NT.)
Was 1NT or 2NT the correct bid at any point in my bidding sequence? Or did I reasonably expect better disclosure of her club holdings?

In modern bidding (according to wikipedia, since the 1980s), negative doubles are oriented entirely toward the unbid majors, and don't promise anything in particular about holdings in the minors. Negative doubles at the 1-level (or even the 2-level in many cases) don't show particularly offense-oriented hands. They may be perfectly happy to defend if opponents come back in. Generally when we're bidding at the 1-level, we're not yet particularly considering offense-defense ratio, because our partnership hasn't had a chance yet to exchange enough information to make a good decision about declaring vs defending.
In this case, when you open a minor, LHO overcalls one spade, and partner doubles, the entire message is around the heart suit. It shows 4 hearts and enough values to force to the two level (probably something like 6 or 7 at a minimum) with no upper limit, OR 5+ hearts without the values to bid 2H (so limited to something like 6-9 points). Partner may have 5-card support for your minor or a void; likewise, they may have length in the unbid minor or not.
Since you don't know you have an 8-card heart fit, you shouldn't advertise to partner that you do. Because the negative double isn't a distributional bid just showing hearts and diamonds, you don't need to stretch to show one of those suits. Here, you're very happy to bid 1NT, so you should do that. This Larry Cohen article describes standard rebids after a negative double; note that the 1NT bid doesn't even necessarily promise a stopper in opponent's suit! By bidding 1NT, you're not giving up on hearts. If partner has a weak hand with long hearts, they can sign off in 2H.

I should say that 2C is also an acceptable bid here if you're uncomfortable bidding 1NT with a stiff diamond. The point is that 2H is not the right bid.

Why are you showing a (non-existent) fourth heart rather than showing your (actually existent) fifth club. Just rebid 2 clubs and stop trying to Hideous Hog your partner.
Re comments below:

While partner is entitled to assume four clubs in your hand when you don't rebid notrump, you need a bid available to show the fifth - especially when it's a decent suit, as here. That is done on this hand with a second round rebid of 2 clubs. Partner has no basis to assume that this shows a sixth club.
I know that a 1 notrump rebid is being floated around this thread, but I can't agree. Partner is entitled to assume that this shows a balanced hand of specifically 12-14 HCP, and despite your good spade stopper I believe that showing the fifth club first is much more important because of the stiff diamond. You really don't want to be playing notrump until you have good assurance that Partner has at least 3 diamonds, and preferably 4, with a holding that opponents cannot easily lead into without giving your side a second trick. You know both opponents have length in this unbid suit, and hence it's coming down at opening lead unless from a holding that is compromised by doing so. Further, you want it played from partner's side and not yours.
So if notrump is the right spot: get there by rebidding 2 clubs first (limiting your range and showing the club length), and then consider cue-bidding spades to show the strong stopper for notrump.


It may be a "club: thing. When people in my club make a demand bid, they expect you to rebid a three card suit. In this context, a rebid of two clubs would imply six, not five. Even so, maybe two clubs is a smaller "lie" than two hearts.

Someone suggested that I rebid 1NT instead of 2 hearts.

I would say this depends on your partnership philosophy about 3 card raises of responder's suit.  Some partnerships frequently raise on 3 card support, risking playing a 4-3 fit; some do it rarely or never.
You should treat the double as a bid of 1H and act accordingly, except that you now can't bid 1S.
A few expert partnerships actually raise 1H to 2H with your hand, even with the 1S rebid available.  I think that's fairly uncommon but not unheard of.
Let's say the bidding went 1C-1S (opps silent), and you hold AJx QJxx x AJxxx.  You're clearly too weak to bid 2H.  Do you bid 1N, 2C, or 2S?
Many (particularly North American) experts take it further.  Over 1C-1S, they'll be bidding 2S with something like AJx QJxx xx AJxx, even with a perfectly good 1N rebid available.  Or they might bid 2S with AJx QJx x AJxxxx with a perfectly good 2C rebid available.
Now - the partnerships that frequently raise responder on 3 card support usually also play conventions (such as some form of spiral raise) to diagnose the 3 card support if responder is interested in game.
How common opener raises responder on 3 will also impact how the partnership reacts to further competition from the opponents.
This being a similar situation, I would suggest for ease of memory to treat it the same.  (Note that, if advancer bids, I do play support doubles in this situation.)
(Personally my preference is to almost never raise on 3 cards, but I would bid 2S after 1C-1S on AJx QJxx x AJxxx (but 2C with Jxx AJxx x AQJxx and 1N with Jxx QJxx A AJxxx (if not playing weak NT)).  Partner is allowed to insist otherwise though.)
Of course you'll have to discuss with partner your partnership philosophy on 3 card raises of responder's suit.  Add this to your new partner discussion checklist (for any partner good enough to appreciate the question).
